# unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-4.2

I am creating one sample application in which i am reading database and displaying user image and name into tableview.
 but i am getting following exception

```
[UIApplication userListMutableArray]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6816330
```

following is my code snippet

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication];

if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)
{
  const char *sql = "select NAME,IMAGE from user";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            UserData *userData = [[UserData alloc] init];
            userData.userName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(selectstmt, 1) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(selectstmt, 1)];
            if(data == nil)
                NSLog(@"image not found");
            userData.userImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];


            **[appDelegate.userListMutableArray addObject:userData];**
        }

    }
}
else
{
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

[appDelegate.userListMutableArray addObject:userData];

above line is giving exception but i am not able to track problem. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your appDelegate variable is pointing to the UIApplication and not its delegate property.  Change this assignment...

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication];
```

to...

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication];
```

to

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```