# iOS [AppDelegate terminateWithSuccess]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I need to implement terminateWithSuccess. I have tried this options [unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093423/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance) and also

```
AppDelegate *myDelegate = [[[AppDelegate alloc]init]autorelease];
 [myDelegate terminateWithSuccess];
```

any of you knows how can implement terminateWithSuccess without any error?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Isn't that a private method?

Comment: Yes it is but I'm using in internal app.

Comment: An app delegate is not normally something you can create directly (kind of like interfaces in Java). This answer has a good explanation of how delegates work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1045854/620197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it this way:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminateWithSuccess];

Comment: It works but I just have a warning "UIApplication may not respond to TerminateWithSuccess"

Comment: That is because it is a private method so the compiler cannot check that it exists.